# What aspect ratio of image should be used for bootstrap carousel without distortion?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap's carousel, and haven't modified any of the CSS.

```
<!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="images/be_blah.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Be blah blah blah</h1>
              <p>Blah blah blah</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
...
```

What size image should I use ? I find that bootstrap tends to "stretch" the images, so they look distorted. Or more correctly, what aspect ratio should I use for my image, so that it is not automatically distorted by bootstrap?

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The carousel [doesn't stretch the images](https://www.codeply.com/go/zOxT2tDKvl) at all. Is there other CSS that could be impacting the images or carousel content? Do you have code that reproduces the issue? Usually `container` wouldn't be used inside carousel items.

Comment: @ZimSystem Only the optional theme specified in the above code.

Comment: @ZimSystem Actually it does seem to distort things a little - it depends on how wide the browser is.